# How do you store a result to a variable and check the result in a conditional?

Tags: perl, perl5.8

I know it's possible but I'm drawing a blank on the syntax. How do you do something similar to the following as a conditional. 5.8, so no switch option:

```
while ( calculate_result() != 1 ) {
    my $result = calculate_result();
    print "Result is $result\n";
}
```

And just something similar to:

```
while ( my $result = calculate_result() != 1 ) {
    print "Result is $result\n";
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add parentheses to specify precedence as `!=` has higher priority than `=`:

```
while ( (my $result = calculate_result()) != 1 ) {
    print "Result is $result\n";
}
```

Comment: That's it. Forgot = returned the assigned value. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[kemp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148968/kemp) has the right answer about precedence. I'd just add that doing complex expressions involving both assignments and comparisons in a loop condition can make code ugly and unreadable very quickly.

I would write it like this:

```
while ( my $result = calculate_result() ) { 
    last if $result == 1;
    print "Result is $result\n";
}
```

Comment: This has a different meaning than the OP. The OP will still execute the block if `$result` is false.

Comment: Yeah, this is really using DateTime's compare(), which is the sub used to override <=> and returns -1, 0, or 1. I need to execute code when it's -1 or 0 and not when 1, and take different paths when -1 and 0.

while($result = compare( $time_a, $time_b)) would never execute, basically.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with:

```
$_ = 1;
sub foo {
   return $_++;
}
while ( ( my $t = foo() ) < 5 )
{
   print $t;
}
```

results in 1234

Answer (score 0):

You were close ...

```
while ( (my $result = calculate_result()) != 1 ) {
    print "Result is $result\n";
}
```